# 403 Forbidden while proxy pass using Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server, web, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a website for which I am using nginx as webserver. 
The wordpress blog of that website is installed on another server. What I want to achieve is that whenever user enter **[www.thewebhoncho.com/blog/][1]** the request should go to the blog server. So, in order to achieve that I have proxy passed from website server to blog server. But when I am trying to access the blog server I am getting 403 forbidden error.

Please find the config for better understanding of the problem:-

Website server nginx config -

```
    server {
            listen 80 ;
           #listen [::]:80 default_Server;
            server_name thewebhoncho.com www.thewebhoncho.com;
            rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;

    }


    server {

            # SSL configuration

            listen 443 ssl default_server;
            server_name www.thewebhoncho.com  thewebhoncho.com;
            ssl_certificate sites-available/thewebhoncho_ssl_cert.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key sites-available/thewebhoncho_ssl_key.key;
            # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
            #
            # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
            # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
            #
            # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
            # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    location / {
                    root /var/www/html;
                    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                    #root /var/www/html/thewebhoncho/web/;
                    index index.php index.html;
                    try_files $uri  $uri/ /thewebhoncho/web/index.html;
                    #try_files $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }


            location /phpmyadmin/ {
            root /usr/share/;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            }
            location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root /usr/share/;
             }
location /blog/ {
            proxy_pass http://205.147.101.173;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         }


        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         #fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         }
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|eot|otf|ttf|woff)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
        access_log off; log_not_found off;
        }
        location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location ~ /\. { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }

}
```

Blog server config :-

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
       #listen [::]:80 default_Server;
        server_name 205.147.101.173;
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
}



server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name 205.147.101.173;

    ssl_certificate sites-available/thewebhoncho_ssl_cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key sites-available/thewebhoncho_ssl_key.key;

    root /var/www/html;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

     client_max_body_size 100M;

    location /blog/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/  index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Error Log of blog server:-

```
2018/07/19 10:19:20 [error] 3904#3904: *1 directory index of "/var/www/html/blog/" is forbidden, client: 18.188.190.81, server: _, request: "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.0", host: "thewebhoncho.com"
2018/07/19 10:27:37 [error] 3904#3904: *3 directory index of "/var/www/html/blog/" is forbidden, client: 18.188.190.81, server: _, request: "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.0", host: "thewebhoncho.com"
```

Permissions:-

```
root@e2e-14-173:~# ll /var/www/html/blog/
total 292
drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data www-data  4096 Jul 18 23:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root      4096 Jul 15 23:03 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 38957 Jun 24 08:31 accesstodb.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   418 Sep 25  2013 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 19935 Jan  6  2018 license.txt
drw-r--r-- 10 www-data www-data  4096 Jun 24 07:20 phpmyadmin/
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Jul 14 17:48 .quarantine/
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  7415 Jul  5 17:09 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data     0 Jul 15 22:50 .test
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 36864 Jul 14 17:33 .tmb/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data   109 Jul 15 22:52 .user.ini*
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   397 Jun 26 12:18 wordfence-waf.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  5458 May  1 22:10 wp-activate.php
drw-r--r--  9 www-data www-data  4096 May 17 19:00 wp-admin/
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   364 Dec 19  2015 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  1889 May  2 22:11 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2839 Jul 15 22:53 wp-config.php
drw-r--r--  8 www-data www-data  4096 Jul 14 17:32 wp-content/
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3669 Aug 20  2017 wp-cron.php
drw-r--r-- 18 www-data www-data 12288 May 17 19:00 wp-includes/
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2422 Nov 21  2016 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3306 Aug 22  2017 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 37760 May 10 21:05 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  8048 Jan 11  2017 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 16246 Oct  4  2017 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 30091 Apr 29 23:10 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  4620 Oct 23  2017 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3065 Aug 31  2016 xmlrpc.php
```

Answer (score 1):

If you directly visit `http://205.147.101.173` from your browser, you'd get the 403 error. Your main server is also proxying to this address, so obviously you'd see the 403 here as well.
Your blog server config doesn't have `location /`, and so you're geting the 403 if you visit `http://205.147.101.173`. `http://205.147.101.173/blog` however should work.

- So try setting your `proxy_pass` to `http://205.147.101.173/blog`.
- Alternatively you could to try changing `location /blog/` to `location /` and  `root /var/www/html` to `root /var/www/html/blog` in your blog server config. So if you visit `http://205.147.101.173` on your browser, you should see your blog.

Comment: Thanks Let me try this and I will let know know.

Comment: @AkhilSharma how did it go? :)